# Android Call Recorder not working properly

Tags: android, audio-recording, telephony, android-mediarecorder

This is what I have done so far. This doesn't record all the calls. It  doesn't produce any error but the recorded file is sometimes empty. I want to record all incoming and outgoing calls. What am i doing wrong ?

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static MediaRecorder callrecorder;
        private static Boolean recording = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String check = prefs.getString("isCheckedIn", null);
            Log.d("Checked In :", check);
            if (check.equals("Yes")) {

                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                    String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
                    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    //                Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
                    Log.d("State", state);

                    switch (state) {

                        case "IDLE":

                            Toast.makeText(context, state + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (recording) {
                                stopRecording();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            break;
                        case "OFFHOOK":
                            PreferencesHelper Prefs = new PreferencesHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
                            String checked = Prefs.GetPreferences("isCheckedIn");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Is CheckedIn :" + checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (checked.equals("Yes")) {
                                if (!recording) {
                                    startRecording();
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            break;
                        case "RINGING":
                            Toast.makeText(context, state + "" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   }
                   }
        void startRecording() {

            //String root="/storage/sdcard0/";
            String fname = "/sales/rec" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".amr";
            //File file=new File(root,fname);
            callrecorder=new MediaRecorder();
            callrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            callrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            callrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            callrecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+fname);
            //callrecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath()
            //callrecorder.setOutputFile(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fname);
            //);
            try {
                callrecorder.prepare();
                callrecorder.start();
                recording = true;
    //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.printStackTrace(),3000 ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        void stopRecording() {

            try {
                callrecorder.stop();
    //      callrecorder.release();
                callrecorder.reset();
                callrecorder = null;
                recording = false;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```